# django syntax error in simple view

Tags: python, django

I'm getting strange syntax error while trying to write django view 
my urls.py is like follows:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'views.index.a123', name='home'),
)
```

my views/index.py is like:

```
# Create your views here.
from django.template import Context, loader
from inventory.models import *
from django.http import HttpResponse

def a123:
    return HttpResponse('HELLO!!!!!!!!!!!')
```

that's what i have:

```
Exception Type:     SyntaxError
Exception Value:    invalid syntax (index.py, line 6)
```

line 6 is:

```
return HttpResponse('HELLO!!!!!!!!!!!')
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need parenthesis with your function declaration:

```
def a123():
```

Remember that *all* Python functions, even those that don't take any arguments, require parenthesis.

Note that this is not the same with classes.  Classes should only have parenthesis if they will be inheriting from something.